# Rest Api HTTPS Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, rest, https

I am developing a new api using rest api php. This API can only operate securely over SSL/TLS. All API requests must be made over HTTPS. Calls made over plain HTTP will fail and the api client must authenticate for all requests. What can we do.

Answer (score 0):

I have used RestServer Controller for this.

A fully RESTful server implementation for CodeIgniter using one library, one config file and one controller.

Here is the link:- https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Just go through the implementation.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes I have already using this package. but This API can only operate securely over SSL/TLS. All API requests must be made over HTTPS. Calls made over plain HTTP will fail and the api client must authenticate for all requests.

Comment: I am not getting clearly what are you looking for. do you want to use http instead of https..?